# CSS style #elements[1-10]

Tags: css, arrays

If I had 5 divs with ids "element1", "element2", etc..., is there a way to style an array of elements with something like:

```
#elements[1-10]{
 position:relative;
}
```

I know you guys probably think I'm nuts, but I'm dealing with some code that is auto generated and I would have to edit the core files of this cms which I don't want to do in case client upgrades in future.

With that said, it is out of the question for me to change the IDs manually to a class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works in many modern browsers... except IE:

```
<style type="text/css">
  p[id*=elements] {
    color: #F00;
  }
</style>
```

**HTML**

```
<p id="elements1">Elements 1</p>
<p id="elements2">Elements 2</p>
<p id="elements3">Elements 3</p>
<p id="elements4">Elements 4</p>
<p id="elements5">Elements 5</p>
```

But there's - of what I know - no way of limiting it.

Comment: Yeah, I need to limit it, but the answer I was looking for was, "there's no way to do it".

Answer (score 3):

I think there's no arrays in CSS. Have you tried considering [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/category/css/)?

Answer (score 3):

If at **all** possible, give all those elements a shared class (e.g., `class="element"`). You can have both an `id` and a `class` attribute and use then in conjunction, so you can leave the auto-generated IDs alone and add your own class for use in styling.

If that's not possible, your only option is to use

```
#element1, #element2, #element3 {
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to do this with CSS but you'll be able to do it with JavaScript (I recommend jQuery.)

Try:

```
var lb = 1;
var ub = 10;
for (var i = lb; i <= ub; i++)
     $("#element" + i).css(*set your css here*);
```

http://jquery.com/

I'm not sure if you can add additional script elements, but this is just something to consider.

Comment: it's pretty simple without jQuery:
`document.getElementById('element' + i).className = 'myCSSClass';`

Comment: That works too. It all comes down to whether you want to add inline styles or just add an existing class to an element.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a pure css method to do it. You are better off using parent child selectors.